# 3 tables 3 columns I need in the WHERE statement to see if they all equal eachother

Tags: mysql

I need something similar to this ... but its not working obviously, not sure if I need to use any JOIN's or what.  Much help is appreciated! Thanks.

vicidial_closer_log.`user` =  vicidial_users.`user` = vicidial_campaign_agents.`user`

```
SELECT
vicidial_closer_log.call_date,
Count(vicidial_closer_log.`status`) AS call_count,
vicidial_closer_log.`user`,
vicidial_closer_log.user_group,
vicidial_users.`user`,
vicidial_users.full_name,
vicidial_campaign_agents.`user`,
vicidial_campaign_agents.campaign_rank
FROM
vicidial_closer_log ,
vicidial_users ,
vicidial_campaign_agents
WHERE
date_format(vicidial_closer_log.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN  '2014-04-02' AND '2014-04-02' AND
vicidial_closer_log.`user` NOT LIKE  'VDCL' AND
vicidial_closer_log.`status` NOT LIKE  'CS' AND
vicidial_closer_log.`status` NOT LIKE  'NANQUE' AND
vicidial_closer_log.`status` NOT LIKE  'TIMEOT' AND
vicidial_closer_log.user_group IN  ('RAD_US', 'RAD_JAM') AND
vicidial_closer_log.`user` =  vicidial_users.`user`
GROUP BY
vicidial_closer_log.`user`
ORDER BY
vicidial_closer_log.`user` ASC
```

Comment: Don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax

Comment: Don't use `NOT LIKE` for literal (constant) strings. It offers horrible performance compared to a simply comparision (`=` or `!=`). You only need the `LIKE` operator when using wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you were doing putting the [vicidial_closer_log.`user` =  vicidial_users.`user`] on WHERE clause isn't completly wrong, but you forgot to link the vicidial_campaign_agents table. If you add a
   AND vicidial_users.user = vicidial_campaign_agents.user
at the end of WHERE clause should work to, but try getting used to the JOIN clause. It's the right way of doing it and makes your query look prettier.

The JOIN clause is very simple, works like this: table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.key = table_b.key. The ON clause specifies what column must match between table_a and table_b and then you JOIN the result of this with table_c doing the same thing.

LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT
l.call_date,
Count(l.status) AS call_count,
l.user,
l.user_group,
u.full_name,
a.campaign_rank
FROM
vicidial_closer_log l
JOIN vicidial_users u ON l.user = u.user
JOIN vicidial_campaign_agents a ON u.user = a.user
WHERE
date_format(l.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-04-02' AND '2014-04-02' AND
l.user <> 'VDCL' AND
l.status NOT IN ('CS', 'NANQUE', 'TIMEOT') AND
l.user_group IN ('RAD_US', 'RAD_JAM')
GROUP BY
l.user
ORDER BY
l.user ASC
```

- I've also added alias to you tables, so your query gets cleaner.
- And also, you don't neet simple quotes to specify table columns like table_a.'column', just type table_a.column.
- And also, the part you typed
  l.status NOT LIKE 'CS' AND
  l.status NOT LIKE 'NANQUE' AND
  l.status NOT LIKE 'TIMEOT'
  you could have typed
  l.status NOT IN ('CS', 'NANQUE', 'TIMEOT')
- And also, you're selecting l.user, u.user and a.user. The way you described your query, these 3 columns will aways be identical on each line, so it's a waste of network traffic when downloading the resultset from the DB server.

I hope it works.

Comment: its giving me the same results as when i did put before what you mentioned.. AND vicidial_users.user = vicidial_campaign_agents.user
same results, its giving me an inaccurate count on the count(status)

Comment: Than it could be another problem. Let's analyze.

The way you are grouping, you will have the ammount of not null l.status for each user. Is that exactly what you want?

Comment: this error is because i've missed a ',' after l.user on SELECT section.

I've corrected it in my answer.

Comment: call counts for the first user they have 44 calls currently http://i.imgur.com/jTeAkhr.png
each call there is a (dispo) status tied to it and im counting those in order to count the amount of calls

Comment: Are each user unique on each table? For example, is the user 1 present on each table only 1 time?

Comment: on the closer log...say that person has 44 calls, he's in there 44 times... on the campaign one multiple times and on the users table just once

Comment: You should notice that when joining tables, one way or another, the DBMS multiplies every row times every row that matches, for example: 1 (from the table users) times 44 (table calls) times X (for the table campaign), so that will be number displayed on the count for this specific user. If you want it to display the number 44 for this user, you should consider excluding the table campaign from this query. Sometimes it's not possible to solve all problems with just one query. You should do one query to count the calls for each user and get the rest of the data you want in a second one.

Comment: which is what i was trying to avoid lol but i figured to at least TRY to get it all with one query but I see what your saying

Comment: Try this:

SELECT
l.user,
count(l.status) AS call_count
FROM
vicidial_closer_log l
JOIN vicidial_users u ON l.user = u.user
WHERE
date_format(l.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-04-02' AND '2014-04-02' AND
l.user <> 'VDCL' AND
l.status NOT IN ('CS', 'NANQUE', 'TIMEOT') AND
l.user_group IN ('RAD_US', 'RAD_JAM')
GROUP BY
l.user
ORDER BY
l.user ASC

Comment: Actualy there IS a way to solve your problem with only one query, but as i can see you're not that much a DataBase guy and it would require more SQL experience, so i recomend splitting your solution into more than one query.

Comment: yea i already got that covered with the calls this probably runs faster than mine tho! fun part to do the campaign query after it and place it in my loop but I can figure that out

Comment: ya and this database I cant edit because its a large dialer system...i cant add or edit any tables in it... im more of a php guy than mysql ur right! hehe

Comment: Consider asking someone you know that have good knowledge in mySQL to help you modeling the tables. Sometimes it's not the query that's wrong, but the table itself.

Comment: ahhhh you are the man!  i added this near the end:  a.campaign_id = '2000' it worked!